# Adding a column with values in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need to add a column with values to a query. A simplified example:

exampleTable:

```
  ID     Fruit
+-----+---------+
|  0  |  Apple  |
+-----+---------+
|  1  |  Pear   |
+-----+---------+
```

I want a query that adds the following hardcoded column name + values:

```
  ID     Fruit     MyFavorite
+-----+---------+-------------+
|  0  |  Apple  |      YES    |
+-----+---------+-------------+
|  1  |  Pear   |      NO     |
+-----+---------+-------------+
```

**To be perfectly clear:** I don't want any new tables, just the query that gives this result.

How can this result be achieved?

**EDIT:** This is just an example with fake tables. I **don't** want any more tables, I **don't** want to alter the existing table and the values in `MyFavorite` are supposed to be hard coded.

Comment: alter table and  add a new column MyFavorite to the table

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV Yeah, but I don't want that.

Comment: You want to add MyFavorite with YES, NO values? What sort of logic do you wish to apply to detemrine whihc rows get YES and which get NO?

Comment: then what you mean ??

Comment: is there any logic behind yes no values ??

Comment: Why is Apple YES and Pear NO? What is the rule you want applied?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner No rule, I want to hardcode it. The table will never change in size

Comment: if yes no has no logic then  your requirement is meaningless

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV remember that this is just an example. Trust me, I have my reasons for why I wish to hardcode them

Comment: Your question is very badly worded. You state that your values are 'hard coded', but to what, and when? As noted by other posters, if your table has a fixed number of rows and values, what is the problem you are actually trying to solve with it? Why are you using tables at all?

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson ok i agree with you. but then you have to change the question heading

Comment: @EdB look, I have a database with lots of tables that I'm not allowed to alter. I was asked to make a query with this output, nothing else.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV ok, what should the question heading be then? I think it says exactly what I want to do

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson what will you do if the table has thousands of rows ???

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV It doesn't

Comment: If you have no rule then you have no choice but to do it manually... either by case statement or by update statements.

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson ok then you can go with this method.

Comment: I didn't downvote. However, in order to hardcode the values in a query one has to know the rules. You were asked to tell us the rule and you said there is none. But if there was no rule on how to apply YES and NO, then YES and NO would be random. This, however is not what you want. You want a rule applied: YES for ID 0, NO for ID 1. Or: YES for Apple, NO for Pear. Saying there was no rule may be the reason for others not to consider your request a valuable entry in this forum.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner either rule is fine. I really don't see how it matters.

Comment: Instead of asking "I have a table that I am not allowed to change, but I want to select YES with Apple and NO with Pear" you said "I have a table I don't want to change and I want to show YES and NO with the records, but there is no rule when to show YES and when NO". This makes quite a difference, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT id
     , fruit
     , CASE fruit 
         WHEN 'Apple' THEN 'YES' 
         ELSE 'NO' 
       END AS MyFavorite
FROM   exampleTable
```

Comment: i did not downvote but i hope he did not say  the logic is based on  value of Fruit column that is why got downvote, but anyway he just say he need the hardcoded values in that kind of view your answer is right

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Will accept as soon as it's possible. Thanks @Mureinik

Answer (score 5):

If you just want a query and don't want to change the table structure:

```
select ID
    ,Fruit
    , CASE WHEN Fruit = 'Apple' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as MyFavorite
from Fruits
```

Comment: he did not say  the logic is based on  value of Fruit column

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by doing this:

```
SELECT yt.id, yt.fruit,
        CASE WHEN YOURLOGIC!
            THEN N'YES' -- if logic = true
            ELSE N'NO' -- if logic = false
        END as MyFavorite
FROM dbo.YourTable as yt
```

But you need to define your logic that lets sql server decide if yes or no.

Answer (score 2):

As the table never changes and you want to hard-code values, why have that table at all? Drop it. Here is the query to give you the desired result:

```
select  0 as id, 'Apple' as fruit, 'YES' as myfavorite
union all
select  1 as id, 'Pear' as fruit, 'NO' as myfavorite;
```

(I don't see the point in hard-coding the values instead of simply having them in a table, but here you go.)

Answer (score 0):

in two steps:
1.

```
 alter mytable add MyFavorite nvarchar(x)
```

2.

```
  update mytable set=
    CASE when Fruit='Apple' then 'YES' 
    else 'NO' 
    END
```